# How to delete a row from csv file on datalake store without using usql?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-data-lake

I am writing a unit test for appending data to CSV file on a datalake. I want to test it by finding my test data appended to the same file and once I found it I want to delete the row I inserted. Basically once I found the test data My test will pass but as the tests are run in production so I have to search for my test data i.e to find the row I have inserted in a file and delete it after the test is run.

I want to do it without using usql inorder to avoid the cost factor involved in using usql. What are the other possible ways we can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a row (or any part) from a file. Azure data lake store is an append-only file system. Data once committed cannot be erased or updated. If you're testing in production, your application needs to be aware of test rows and ignore them appropriately.

The other choice is to read all the rows in U-SQL and then write an output excluding the test rows.

Answer (score 0):

Like other big data analytics platforms, ADLA / U-SQL does not support appending to files per se.  What you can do is take an input file, append some content to it (eg via U-SQL) and write it out as another file, eg a simple example:

```
DECLARE @inputFilepath string = "input/input79.txt";
DECLARE @outputFilepath string = "output/output.txt";


@input =
    EXTRACT col1 int,
            col2 DateTime,
            col3 string
    FROM @inputFilepath
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1);


@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @input

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM(
        VALUES
        (
            2,
            DateTime.Now,
            "some string"
        ) ) AS x (col1, col2, col3);


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFilepath
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false, outputHeader : true);
```

If you want further control, you can do some things via the Powershell SDK, eg test an item exists:

```
Test-AdlStoreItem -Account $adls -Path "/data.csv"
```

or move an item with `Move-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem`.  More details here:

[Manage Azure Data Lake Analytics using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-powershell)